# Is $x \sin(1/x)$ decreasing or increasing?

Tags: functions, derivatives

How can I show that $x.\sin(1/x)$ is decreasing?

Actually, this question is coming from the series that I trying to solve by using alterne series test. I have a series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n \sin(1/n).$$ B.t.w., series is divergent since limit of this $f(n)$ is not $0$ so it is necessary to check first condition of Alterne series test. But I wanted to determine.

I tried to compute derivative, but I believe it doesn’t work. Any suggestion?

Comment: What if it is neither?

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether it is decreasing (or possibly increasing) in some interval? If so, please give the interval; otherwise, as the above comment and the first answer indicate, it is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

This function has infinitely many local extremes. Indeed, set $f(x)=s\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ and note that
$$
f'(x)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
Hence, $f'(x)=0$ iff $\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}$. But the equation $\tan t=t$  has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Taylor series, it seems obvious enough that the function is increasing for $x\geq 1.$

You can compute the derivative (already done in another answer) but I don’t think that provides a simpler solution.